# Huge firebase admob stacktrace listing - related to FirebaseAdMobPlugin?

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob

Through of all the listing the following `FirebaseAdMobPlugin` repeated several times

```
firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.callInitialize(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (FirebaseAdMobPlugin.java:219)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.onMethodCall(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (FirebaseAdMobPlugin.java:471)
```

I supopse the reason is the plugin itself but what's the reason?

the complete listing when project start

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1305/ZyhRqAoaw4I=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/OpenGLRenderer(16725): HWUI GL Pipeline
I/OpenGLRenderer(16725): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(16725): Swap behavior 1
D/        (16725): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xcf4a38c0, tid 16947
W/OpenGLRenderer(16725): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer(16725): Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation(16725): eglCreateContext: 0xe16be740: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation(16725): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe16be740: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xcf4994d0)
E/eglCodecCommon(16725): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon(16725): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
D/        (16725): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd386f200, tid 16828
D/EGL_emulation(16725): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe16bd660: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe4783f20)
E/eglCodecCommon(16725): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon(16725): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
D/EGL_emulation(16725): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe16be740: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xcf4994d0)
D/EGL_emulation(16725): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe16bd660: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe4783f20)
I/WebViewFactory(16725): Loading com.android.chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (code 349710017)
I/zygote  (16725): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/zygote  (16725): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uJ>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4574)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4706)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:643)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:548)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz.<init>(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz.zzb(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgt.get() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdwe) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:13)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgj com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgr.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:8)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakk.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:6)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakr.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalm) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:49)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaku.run() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:-1)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbca.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:4)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbcd.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:4)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalm com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakr.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:17)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzali com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakr.zzb(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:31)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzc com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamg.zzi(java.lang.Object) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:10)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxy, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:42)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbld.zza(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:80)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzd.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:36)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:6)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.callInitialize(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (FirebaseAdMobPlugin.java:219)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.onMethodCall(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (FirebaseAdMobPlugin.java:471)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(java.nio.ByteBuffer, io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger$BinaryReply) (MethodChannel.java:233)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (DartMessenger.java:85)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (FlutterJNI.java:692)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:325)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:142)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
I/zygote  (16725): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/Chrome/lib/x86, /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4574)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4706)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:643)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:548)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz.<init>(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz.zzb(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgt.get() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdwe) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:13)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgj com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgr.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:8)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakk.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:6)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakr.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalm) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:49)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaku.run() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:-1)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbca.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:4)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbcd.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:4)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalm com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakr.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:17)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzali com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzakr.zzb(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:31)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzc com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamg.zzi(java.lang.Object) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:10)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaxy, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:42)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbld.zza(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:80)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzd.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:36)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:6)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.callInitialize(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (FirebaseAdMobPlugin.java:219)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.onMethodCall(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (FirebaseAdMobPlugin.java:471)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(java.nio.ByteBuffer, io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger$BinaryReply) (MethodChannel.java:233)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (DartMessenger.java:85)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (FlutterJNI.java:692)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:325)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:142)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
I/zygote  (16725): 
I/zygote  (16725): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uJ>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
I/zygote  (16725):   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4574)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4706)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:643)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:548)
I/zygote  (16725):   at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz.<init>(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgz.zzb(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhy, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeg, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbx, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabs, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzts, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsu, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnv, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnw) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:2)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgt.get() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.4.0:3)
I/zygote  (16725):   at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay.zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdwe) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:13)
I/zygote  (16725):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgj  
...
```